# Encrypt large string in Delphi

Tags: delphi

i'm using this method to encrypt small string's for a long time and work just fine..
when i try to pass a large string (lenght > 500) it dont work
someone can tell me why?

```
`function Encrypt(const Text: string): string;
var
  i: Byte;
  Key: Word;
  strTemp: string;
const
  KEY  = 7519;
  KEY1 = 03001;
  KEY2 = 002279;
begin
  Key := KEY;
  SetLength(strTemp, Length(Text));
  Result := '';
  for i := 1 to Length(Text) do
  begin
    strTemp[i] := Char(byte(Text[I]) xor (Key shr 8));
    Result := Result + IntToHex(Byte(strTemp[i]), 2);
    Key := (Byte(strTemp[i]) + KEY) * KEY1 + KEY2 ;
  end;
end;`
```

i tried to pass a large value in base64 with approximately 5000 characters, the result after encryption is approximately 250 characters..

i'm trying to encrypt a base64 text.. base64 extracted from a .jpeg

example:

```
    var vText: AnsiString;
    vText := 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAAAQ4CAYAAADo08FDAAAgAElEQVR4XuydUbbjOJIss5bR+19oz' + '1Fla1KpS4kgCcLdI+z9XpBhbgGRfIisnn/+85///PcX/w8DGMAABsoa+Oeff8pmew1WMWelTJWyPPZdt' +'TzP31LVXO8PwS45jz788XLUmMd6+ubRh8oU//0vRwZp/aVnnzvWxU3FnNUyVcpTKcvz6VExzFgtU6U8l' +'bJUHGp/e09U693eO5G/YwADGOhggAFwhy6TEQMYaGegy0FyxZyVMpHF99FTqTcMfsf2';
```

Result = 6EA0B289D3DB602BC0EFCC2F2B38A54FF5916CE39FF43E4F7CACFFF7BB372D2E5485038DE606514C0BC943D55B9246C8

Comment: At what string size does the problem start? That will give you a clue.

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using? Since Delphi 2009 the ``string`` type switched from Ansi to Unicode. That means, one character does not equal one byte anymore. So your ``byte``-casts look very suspicious!

Comment: Maybe the encryption logic causes some character to become #0, and the method you use to look at the encrypted string stops outputting there (i.e. it sees the string as if it were null-terminated)?

Comment: @rossum, sometimes 128.. other time 250.. its random

Comment: @DelphiCoder what could I do?

Comment: @MatthiasB I've tried in memo, showmessage and database.. the final result is always the same if that's what you meant..

Comment: Edit your question: add multiple examples of actual code how you call your function. Yes, with one such large String. Also mention which Delphi version you're using. Tell us what happens in your case per each example.

Comment: I'm using Delphi 10.4

Comment: This isn't encryption as such, in that it's simple for people to reverse it. Encryption algorithms convert arrays of bytes into arrays of bytes. They don't operate on strings. Convert your string to UTF8 bytes. Then encrypt using actual off the shelf encryption algos. Then encode those bytes using base64.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan show me an example

Comment: If you pass in an AnsiString value, then why is the paramater of ``Encrypt`` not an AnsiString, too!?

Comment: @DelphiCoder its just an example..string or ansi the result is the same..

Comment: Did you switch ``strTemp`` to AnsiString, too?

Comment: @DelphiCoder
Yes. Same result.

Comment: There are countless examples of converting text to UTF-8, encryting byte arrays (i.e. your UTF-8 bytes) and converting bytes to base64 strings. This is a topic that has been covered endlessly. Why don't you look for yourself rather than asking us to make yet another example?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan why dont you pont any of that examples? thank you. answer has been done.. not by you of course, you came here just for.. what?

Comment: If you can't use a search engine to find things then it's gonna tough going

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Your program **cannot compile** as you show it in this example, because of

   ```pascal
   var
     Key: Word;
   const
     KEY  = 7519;
   ```

   You tagged this question *Delphi*, and by that identifiers are case insensitive: `KEY` cannot be defined since `Key` already exists. This might be possible in *Pascal* alone, tho. So please check the example you gave us against your actual code.
2. Your loop variable is **not big enough**:

   ```pascal
   var
     i: Byte;
   begin
     for i := 1 to Length(Text) do
   ```

   Should `Length(Text)` be 304, then the loop will run 48 iterations only, because `Byte` can at max hold 256 values. Should a loop end condition have a higher value than the variable is able to ever hold, the maximum amount of the variable is subtracted from that end condition. Which is 304 minus 256 equals 48.
3. Why do you need a **temporary String** when you only need one single character? And even then you only treat is as Byte anyway, so why not using that?

   ```pascal
   var
     strTemp: string;
   begin
     SetLength(strTemp, Length(Text));
     for i := 1 to Length(Text) do
     begin
       strTemp[i] := Char(...);
       Result := Result + IntToHex(Byte(strTemp[i]), 2);
       Key := (Byte(strTemp[i]) ...)...;
   ```

   This can be written a lot cleaner as:

   ```
   var
     byteTemp: Byte;
   begin
     for i := 1 to Length(Text) do
     begin
       byteTemp := Byte(Text[I]) xor (Key shr 8);
       Result := Result + IntToHex(byteTemp, 2);
       Key := (byteTemp + KEY0) * KEY1 + KEY2;
   ```
4. **Never encrypt text** - encrypt bytes instead. The declaration

   ```pascal
   function Encrypt(const Text: string): string;
   ```

   will differ as per Delphi version. Why not making it at least `AnsiString`? Or even better: `TBytes` or `Array of Byte`? When dealing with any kind of `String` you can never be certain how many bytes one character needs. Using `String` in Delphi 2009 and above uses more than 1 byte per character, so with `Byte(String[i])` you're walking on thin ice.

Comment: Why not use Encrypt

Comment: @Info Yes, exactly - that's the whole point of my post and its explanations.